# How to iterate through List which conatins both dict and list in a tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am having a list in python which contains list of dict with list of dict, like
Data = [{k: v}, [{k, v}, [{k,v}, {k,v}, {k,v}]]] I am adding another sample below for reference.

Basically, it is a tree where dict is a child of list. How can i process this data in python?

```
[
  [
    {
      "a":"value",
      "b":"value",
      "c":"value"
    },
    [
      {
        "aa":"value",
        "bb":"value",
        "cc":"value"
      },
      [
        {
          "aaa":"value",
          "bbb":"value",
          "ccc":"value"
        },
        {
          "aaa":"value",
          "bbb":"value",
          "ccc":"value"
        },
        {
          "aaa":"value",
          "bbb":"value",
          "ccc":"value"
        },
       ],
      ]
    ],
  [
    {
      "x":"value",
      "y":"value",
      "z":"value"
    },
    [
      {
        "xx":"value",
        "yy":"value",
        "zz":"value"
      },
      [
        {
          "xxx":"value",
          "yyy":"value",
          "zzz":"value"
        },
        {
          "xxx":"value",
          "yyy":"value",
          "zzz":"value"
        },
        {
          "xxx":"value",
          "yyy":"value",
          "zzz":"value"
        }
      ], 
    ],     
  ]
]
```

I am looking for output something like this or first it has to process the dict and then go to the list.

```
a--|
   |__ aa--|
   |       |__ aaa
   |       |
   |       |__ bbb
   |       |
   |       |__ ccc
   |
   |
   |__ bb--|
           |__ aaa
           |
           |__ bbb
           |
           |__ ccc
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You iterate through the list, checking the element types, and handling each appropriately.  Many other posts demonstrate how to do this.
See [How much research?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to iterate all of the elements and you don't know the depth, you should probably do that by using a recursion.

Here is an example:

```
def process_list_deep(items):
    for item in items:
        if type(item) is list:
            process_list_deep(item)
        else:
            # process the (dict) item here...
```